# Copy a frame contents into a Sheet (vba)

Tags: vba, excel, frame, worksheet

I have a frame in a userform, in this frame i have pictures and labels. I need to put the whole frame exactly is this in userform, put directly into a sheet.

Im using this code to create a frame into sheet, and receive the picture of frame in the userform. But in this case, only the picutre will be copied, not the labels.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim oCheck As OLEObject

For Each oCheck In Plan1.OLEObjects
    oCheck.Delete
Next oCheck

With Plan1.OLEObjects.Add(classtype:="Forms.Frame.1", _
    Top:=260, Left:=25, Height:=273, Width:=490)
        .Object.Caption = ""
        .Object.Picture = Me.Frame1.Picture
        .Object.BackColor = "&HFFFFFF"
End With
```

Any Sugestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has been crossposted here: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?60787-Copy-whole-frame-content-to-worksheet&p=369690&viewfull=1#post369690

Comment: Want to upvote this for the content, but want to downvote as well as it should have been a comment.  Feeling torn now. :(

Comment: Abject apologies :-(